# How to prove $f:[x] → (\cos 2\pi x, \sin 2\pi x)$ is a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

$[x]$ is the set that paste $0$ and $1$ as one point in $[0,1]$.

I have proved that $f$ is objective. But how to prove $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous? Any suggestion shall be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean bijective?

Answer (score 1):

Let $q$ be the map that sends $x$ in $[0,1]$ to $[x]$ in $[0,1]{/}\sim$ where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation that only identifies $0$ and $1$.

As $[0,1]{/}\sim$ has the quotient topology w.r.t. $q$, a map $f: [0,1]{/}\sim \to Y$ is continuous iff $f \circ q: [0,1] \to Y$ is continuous, and it's hopefully clear that $f \circ q$ is the map that sends $x$ to $(\cos 2\pi x, \sin 2\pi x)$ and is this continuous as $\cos$ and $\sin$ are.

As $f$ is a bijection, and $Y=\Bbb S^1$ is Hausdorff and $[0,1]{/}\sim$ is compact (as the continuous image $q[[0,1]]$), $f$ is closed and so $f^{-1}$ is continuous.